# I need to vertical align an image in a label

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this post has been done so many times but for some odd reason`vertical-align:middle;`doesn't seem to work.

I am trying to get everything inside the `<label></lable>` element to vertically align

Text and `<strong></strong>` must stay left.

The `<strong></strong>` text font size must be smaller than the `<lable></lable>` text and also vertically align with the `<lable></lable>` text.

Image must `float:right;` and vertically align with the `<lable></lable>` text.

At the end it looks like images below but I want everything to auto align vertically without setting margins or padding as this could affect the layout on the mobile layout.

**Please any help would be greatly appreciated.**

[image]

I use `var.style.display = 'inline-block';` and  `var.src = '/img_1.png';`  to change the image and for border colour I use `var.style.borederColor = "#fff"`.

[image]

And to display the error or OK I use `var.innerHTML = 'msg';` to change the `<strong>`'s inner html.

[image]

All the `display: inline-block;` values get changed from `display:none;` to `display:inline-block;` by Javascript to display an image and an error message inside the `<label>`on failure of validation.

I have a label above a text input that needs all it's content vertically aligned.
Inside I have:

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <label class="fine">LABEL NAME
        <strong>ERROR MESSAGE</strong><!--innerHTML changed by JS-->
        <img src="img.png"><!--src changed by JS-->
    </label>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
form label.fine{
    display: inline-block; 
    background-color: #212121;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding:0 0.5em 0 0.5em;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ff2222; // Changed by JS
    border-radius:0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;
}

form label.fine img {
    display: inline-block; //Originally set to "none" and changed to "inline-block" by JS
    float: right;
}

form label.fine strong{
    font-size: 0.6em;
    color:#ff2222; //changed by JS
    text-decoration:bold;
}
```

Comment: you can not combine `float` and `display: inline-block`. When you use `float:right;` the image will become `display: block;`

Comment: JSfiddle required (with image please).

Comment: Did you consider using a background-image for the indicator image?

Comment: Thanx @NicoO this did the trick for the image. 
But Now to get the `<strong>` aligned

Comment: you can add a new `<span>` around the Label text and make this `inline-block`. When you don't give a height to `<label>` but a equal button and top padding the result should be as desired. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/smTCA/1/

Comment: Nope...
Add an "|"(or) symbol to the from of that line and see what happens. 
Looks aligned but it's not really.

I'll just make both label and error the same size and a bit smaller. 
This OCD will be the end of me one day.
Looks great either way will post images in a sec.

Thanx for the help though @NicoO

Comment: use `vertical-align: baseline;` then: http://jsfiddle.net/smTCA/2/

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```
<img class="position" src="img.png" alt="">
```

CSS:

```
.position { vertical-align: super; }
```

This should help you

Comment: The image is meant to be vertically aligned.

Answer (score -1):

I would probably position the image absolutely and add position: relative to form label.fine

Comment: Not an answer. This should have been a comment.